# How to get pppd to create ppp0 inside namespace?

Tags: iproute, namespace, pppd

I have a simple pppoe connection which is working fine. A simple

```
# pon my-isp
```

creates a `ppp0` device.

I have defined a namespace like

```
ip netns add physical
```

but after

```
ip netns exec physical pon my-isp
```

does not create a `ppp0` neither in global namespace nor in `physical` namespace.

How can I get a ppp0 inside the mentioned namespace?

Comment: Can `pppd` access the PPPoE device from the namespace? I guess you need a veth pair and have to bridge the outer one with your real ethernet interface.

Answer (score 0):

Ideas:

1) Let `pon` create the device in the default namespace, then move it into `physical`. Script the process.

2) `pon` is just a script, if you look at it, it calls `pppd`. Copy the script, modify it so that it uses `netns exec` to call `pppd`. See if that solves the problem. As Hauke has said, you need the PPPoE device in the namespace. A veth pair may or may not be necessary, depending on what you want to do with the namespace.

**Edit**

I don't know your exact setup (all ppp and pppoe configuration files are missing from the description), so I tried out a simplified setup that connects two namespaces via PPPoE. As expected, starting `pppd` in a namespace makes the `ppp0` device appear in that namespace, so I really don't know what goes wrong in your configuration.

Test the following (as root):

```
ip netns add ns1
ip netns add ns2
ip link add veth1 type veth peer name veth2
ip link set veth1 addr 52:54:00:00:00:01
ip link set veth2 addr 52:54:00:00:00:02
ip link set veth1 netns ns1
ip link set veth2 netns ns2
ip -n ns1 link set lo up
ip -n ns1 link set veth1 up
ip -n ns2 link set lo up
ip -n ns2 link set veth2 up    
ip netns exec ns1 pppd pty '/usr/sbin/pppoe -I veth1 -e 1:52:54:00:00:00:02 -m 1412' noaccomp nopcomp asyncmap 000a0008 noauth nocrtscts xonxoff local maxfail 0 192.168.36.1:192.168.36.2
ip netns exec ns2 pppd pty '/usr/sbin/pppoe -I veth2 -e 1:52:54:00:00:00:01 -m 1412' noaccomp nopcomp asyncmap 000a0008 noauth nocrtscts xonxoff local maxfail 0 192.168.36.2:192.168.36.1
```

Now start two `xterms` in the namespace as user `username`, so you can look at the configuration, test with `ping` etc (I like to have colored backgrounds for this, so I know which is which):

```
ip netns exec ns1 su -c "xterm -bg yellow &" username
ip netns exec ns2 su -c "xterm -bg lime &" username
```

If that works, something in the way your PPPoE-scripts set up things is in the way. If it doesn't work, something else is wrong.

Comment: I have added all physical devices into one namespace like `ip link set enp5s0f0 netns physical`. After this a normal `pppd call my-isp` does not work. `ip netns  exec physical pppd call ` starts. I can see `pppd` in the process list. But no ppp0 device apears. Not in `global` or `physical` namespace.